# ASP.NET Core 2.2 is not firing Validate method in IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to do some custom validation but I cannot seem to get the validation method to fire. Please let me know what I might be missing. Thanks!

Following is my code:

Model:

```
public class TestModel : IValidatableObject
{
   [Required]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      if (FirstName == "Hello")
           yield return ValidationResult.Success;
      else
           yield return new ValidationResult("Error from Validate method");
   }

}
```

View:

```
@model EswSigningServer.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<h4>TestModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Test">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Test" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   TestModel createKey = new TestModel();
   return View(createKey);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Test(IFormCollection collection)
{
   try
   {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             // TODO: Add insert logic here
             return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
             return View();
        }
   }
   catch
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

I've also tried adding the validator to a single attribute using the following method and that doesn't fire either:

```
    public class MyValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Hello");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`IValidatableObject` is a class-level validation. When model binding , it will call the `Validate` method determines whether the specified object is valid .If you want to get the validation method to fire , you should change the parameter type of Test method to `TestModel` as shown:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Test(TestModel model)
```